# replace specific element of rdd in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to replace the first element of each rdd list.

First I convert rdd string to rdd list with:

```
ff = rdd.map(lambda x:  x.split(","))
simpleRDD = ff.map(lambda x: x) 
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(simpleRDD.glom().collect()))
```

> Partitions structure (example): [[['2020-05-22 12:36:12','240144','54'],
>   ['2020-05-22 12:36:12','32456','64']]]

I want to replace the first element of each rdd list i.e.'2020-05-22 12:36:12','2020-05-22 12:36:12' with a different value.

I have tried `replaceRDD = simpleRDD.map(lambda a: ("new" if a[0] else "new"))` but this replace all elements with "*new*".

How to achive something like this:

> Partitions structure (example): [[['myvalue','240144','54'],
>   ['myvalue','32456','64']]]

Comment: Write a function for what you want to do with the first element, and apply it on the first element, that should work

Comment: if I use a function I does not work, maybe i do something wrong.

Comment: Can you post that function? Because `lambda a: ("new" if a[0] else "new")` doesn't make sense, right

Comment: lambda a: (replace_func(a[0])) where 
def replace_func(x):
    x = "my value". it returns None in every element

Comment: There is no `return` statement in the function

Comment: my bad. i add a return x. but then I have [['my value', 'my value']]. I want to change only the first element of each rdd list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an rdd like so:

```
words = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([["scala", "java", "hadoop"],[ "spark", "akka","spark"], ["hadoop", "pyspark", "kafka"]])
```

And you want to convert the first element to something, I will take an example of replacing the first element/word to it's length:

```
def len_replace(string):
    return len(string)

words.map(lambda x: ([len_replace(x[0])] + x[1:])).take(3)
# Output
# [[5, 'java', 'hadoop'], [5, 'akka', 'spark'], [6, 'pyspark', 'kafka']]
```

You replace the first element by passing `x[0]` to the function, and you need the rest of the elements also so you add another term to the tuple which is `x[1:]`, which says give me all elements from index 1 till the end.